# Android: async loaded bitmaps randomly don't appear in ImageView after ImageView.setBitmapDrawable(..)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-imageview, loopj

I have a ListView whose elements are photos I need to load from a remote API which I'm using loopj to access.

After loopj downloads the photo data, I use an AsyncTask to process the data into a scaled bitmap.

This usually works great, however..

**The problem**

In my AsyncTask's onPostExecute method, I call setImageBitmap on the ImageView. Occasionally, the bitmap simply doesn't appear in the ImageView after ImageView.setImageBitmap is called. I have verified through logs and also the debugger that ImageView.setImageBitmap is indeed called on the offending ImageView.

If I scroll the list a bit, the list element redraws, and the image is loaded from memory cache and correctly appears on the ImageView.

Here's my code:

```
public void setPersonImage(final ImageView personImageView, final Person p) {
    personImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_image);

    //kills unecessary requests for the imageview's previous occupant photo
    if(personImageView.getTag() != null) {
        AsyncHttpClient client = mPhotoRequestsMap.get(p.getEmployeeId());
        if(client != null) {
            client.cancelRequests(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), true);
            Log.d(TAG, "Cancled photo request for " + String.valueOf(p.getEmployeeId()));
        }
    }

    personImageView.setTag(p.getEmployeeId());

    //first attempt to grab photo from cache
    Bitmap cachedBitmap = mMemoryCache.get(p.getPhotoCacheKey());
    if(cachedBitmap != null) {
        personImageView.setImageBitmap(cachedBitmap);
        Log.d(TAG, "bitmap for " + String.valueOf(p.getEmployeeId()) + " retrieved from memory cache");
    } else {

        AsyncHttpClient client = ApiWrapper.getPersonImage(180,mUserSession, 
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(), p.getEmployeeId(),
            new MyAsyncHttpResponseHandler(this) {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    if(personImageView.getTag().equals(p.getEmployeeId())) {
                        // use async task to process the bitmap off the UI thread
                        AsyncTask<String,Integer,Bitmap> task = new AsyncTask<String,Integer,Bitmap>() {
                            @Override
                            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                                String response = params[0];
                                byte[] bitmapBytes = ApiWrapper.processImageResponse(response);
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapBytes.length);
                                Bitmap bmpScaled = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, 180, 180);
                                return bmpScaled;
                            }

                            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                                //set on imageview if tags agree 
                                if(personImageView.getTag().equals(p.getEmployeeId())) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "setting image view for " + p.getEmployeeId());
                                    personImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                    mMemoryCache.put(p.getPhotoCacheKey(), bitmap);

                                }
                                else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "tags don't match after decode bitmap, discarding...");
                                }
                            }

                        };

                        task.execute(response);
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "tags don't match BEFORE decode bitmap employee id: " + p.getEmployeeId() + " tag: " + personImageView.getTag());
                    }
               }


           }
        );

        //create entry in PhotoRequestsMap table
        mPhotoRequestsMap.put(p.getEmployeeId(), client);

    } // end if not in cache
}
```

I've tried calling invalidate() on the ImageView after the bitmap is set on it, but sadly that doesn't solve it..

I'd greatly appreciate any help or pointers.

**Update**

The getView method from my Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
            if (convertView == null) {
               convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_person, null);
            }

            Person p = getItem(position);

            TextView nameTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_ListItemNameTextView);
            nameTextView.setText(p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName());

            TextView idTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_ListItemIdTextView);
            idTextView.setText(String.valueOf(p.getEmployeeId()));

            ImageView personImageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_ListItemImageView);
            setPersonImage(personImageView, p);

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: `personImageView` is being called multiple times, before the first AsyncTask finishes, the second overwrites it. Try making array of objects.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are re-using the same Imageviews for different List rows? Is it possible to see the `getView(...)` method from your adapter?

Comment: @ErnirErlingsson I think android will recycle the imageViews themselves by default.. I am caching the bitmaps though. I updated the question with my getView() method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the `.setImageBitmap(Bitmap)` method is working fine, you are just setting it with `null`.

Check for the case of `bitmap == null` in the `onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)`. This also fits to your observation that the image appears when you scroll, because Android calls `getView(..)` again for the visible rows at that time.

Comment: The bitmaps being set are not null. I've verified this through the debugger and also just now by adding a null check like you described. I'm seeing the same result.. Thanks for trying, though :)

Comment: Did you try to inflate a new View every time `getView(..)` is called? Try removing the `if (convertView == null)` and check if the problem persists (not that I am recommending it, just to check if the problem lies with the View's re-usage).

Comment: I removed the if (convertView == null) and it appears to be working! I'm trying to figure out what I should do now since inflating the view every time probably isn't a sustainable approach?

Comment: Correct! That is too slow. I suspect the problem is related to the canceling code. Put `if (convertView == null)` back in, and this time try removing the `client.cancelRequest..` code.

Comment: It looks like you are right. I removed the canceling code and it now works as expected. The canceling code deals with the problem of if the user flings through a long list of images that need to be loaded, the app will make a lot of unnecessary requests. How is this problem typically dealt with?

Comment: Typically this is correct, however, there is obviously something wrong with this particular code. My hunch is that it lies with the `AsyncHttpClient` library, which I have not used. Make sure that .getPersonImage(..) is returning a unique object, also make sure that .getEmployeeId() returns a unique identifier for different instantiations.